# How to set wick color based on candle body color in pine script v4?

Tags: pine-script

```
palette = ( abs(open-close)/abs(high-low) > 0.5 )? open < close ? color.green : color.red : color.blue
plotcandle(choice =="Candle" ? value_open:na,value_high,value_low,value_close,color=palette,**wickcolor=(value_close > value_open ? color.green:color.red)**)
```

value_high, value_low, value_open, value_close is custom high, low, open, close variable that is working fine issue is only with wickcolor.

I am trying this above code but it's not returning the value of color... How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the refman for [`plotcandle()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_plotcandle), contrary to the body's color which can be a *series color* (so vary on each bar), the `wickcolor` parameter requires an *input color*, which entails it must be known before the script executes.

To overcome this constraint, we need to use separate `plotcandle()` calls for each color, and your script must have room for the 8 additional plots this adds to your script's total plot count (4 plots / `plotcandle()` call).

It's not pretty but it works:

```
//@version=4
study("")
choice = input("Candle")
value_open = open
value_high = high
value_low = low
value_close = close
palette = (abs(open - close) / abs(high - low) > 0.5 ) ? open < close ? color.green : color.red : color.blue

// Returns a value `_v` only if user wants to plot candle and `palette` matches the required color `_c`.
f_v(_c, _v) => choice == "Candle" and palette == _c ? _v : na

c_g = color.green
plotcandle(f_v(c_g, value_open), f_v(c_g, value_high), f_v(c_g, value_low), f_v(c_g, value_close), color = c_g, wickcolor = c_g)
c_r = color.red
plotcandle(f_v(c_r, value_open), f_v(c_r, value_high), f_v(c_r, value_low), f_v(c_r, value_close), color = c_r, wickcolor = c_r)
c_b = color.blue
plotcandle(f_v(c_b, value_open), f_v(c_b, value_high), f_v(c_b, value_low), f_v(c_b, value_close), color = c_b, wickcolor = c_b)
```

[image]

I use the same technique in my [Delta Volume Candles [LucF]](https://www.tradingview.com/script/h0yZPTiS-Delta-Volume-Candles-LucF/) script.